# How to add date filter to mysql. Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

```
<?php
        $database = & JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT asset_id FROM #__content WHERE state = 1";
        $database->setQuery( $query );
        $count_at = $database->loadObjectList();
        $count_nbr = count($count_at);
?>
```

So `$count_nbr` returns all created and published articles, but i need to add "today" filter to it. If some guru could hep ot please... Need 2 types of filter: "1 day" and a "week"...

UPDATE: adding `$date = date (Y-m-d);` amd modifieng string to `SELECT asset_id FROM #__content WHERE state = 1 AND publish_up = $date;` doen't help cause publish_up in mysql Y-m-d H:i:s and I need to ignore time stamp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the articles published today:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$query = "SELECT asset_id FROM #__content WHERE state = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(publish_up, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$today'";
...
```

This uses the MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function to format that published date to `Y-m-d` format, so that you can compare it.

To get articles published this week use the [`YEARWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function:

```
$query = "SELECT asset_id FROM #__content WHERE state = 1 AND YEARWEEK(publish_up) = YEARWEEK(NOW())";
```

Comment: And what about week option?

Comment: @AndrewSekaev added the week option